# Peewee: filtering by many-to-many relationship

Tags: python, orm, peewee

Here's a basic example - posts are owned and liked by users. How to select liked posts for specific user?

```
import datetime
import peewee

class User(peewee.Model):
    name = peewee.CharField(max_length=200)

class Post(peewee.Model):
    user = peewee.ForeignKeyField(User)
    text = peewee.TextField()

class Like(peewee.Model):
    user = peewee.ForeignKeyField(User)
    post = peewee.ForeignKeyField(Post)
    time = peewee.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

I make a query from perspective of Like model, starting query with `Like.select()` and join `Post` model. Is it ok? How could I query from perspective of `Post` model, i.e. `Post.select()...`?

Here's a complete sample for convinience:

```
def check_likes():
    user, _ = User.get_or_create(name="John")
    post, _ = Post.get_or_create(text="Hello world!", user=user)
    like, _ = Like.get_or_create(post=post, user=user)

    print("Created: ", user, post, like)

    # Get liked posts for user
    query_likes = (Like.select()
        .where(Like.user == user)
        .join(User)
        .join(Post))
    liked_posts = [like.post for like in query_likes]

    print("Liked posts: ", liked_posts)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    User.create_table(True)
    Post.create_table(True)
    Like.create_table(True)

    check_likes()
```

UPD. I ended up with such query at the moment:

```
def liked_by(user_id):
    """Active posts liked by user."""
    return (Post.select(Post, User, Like)
        .join(User, on=(Post.user == User.id))
        .switch(Post)
        .join(Like, peewee.JOIN.LEFT_OUTER,
              on=(Like.post == Post.id).alias('like'))
        .where(Like.user == user_id)
        .order_by(Like.time.desc()))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The query above should work, but you might modify it to read:

```
Like.select(Like, Post)...
```

You also need to take care about how you are joining on tables. Use the 'switch' method:

```
query_likes = (Like.select(Like, Post)  # <<< Add like and post
    .where(Like.user == user)
    .join(User)
    .switch(Like)  # <<< You need this.
    .join(Post))
liked_posts = [like.post for like in query_likes]
```

You can also do:

```
Post.select().join(Like).where(Like.user == some_user)
```

Comment: Thank you Charles! I ended up with query as in `liked_by()` in updated question. Not sure if I really need `JOIN.LEFT_OUTER` here.

I also needed to specify `on` statements in my real code, not sure when it's required, but I use UUID primary keys and seems like it's required in some cases, so I decided to add it everywhere :)

Comment: Hmm... seems like there's no actually need to `JOIN.LEFT_OUTER` here. It may be needed in another case - query all posts without filtering + join likes by particular user. Right?